# MemoryError: not enough memory to deal with big matrix

Tags: python, windows, memory, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn to do dimension reduction from csv data. The size is 25,000X300. My environment is windows with 16GB memory. Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.manifold import MDS

array = np.loadtxt('mnist_train2.csv',delimiter=',')
mds = MDS(n_components=2,max_iter=100)
array_MDS = mds.fit_transform(array)
pd.DataFrame(array_MDS).to_csv("mds.csv",index=None)
```

The error message is(22.5GiB in another computer)

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.53 GiB for an array with shape (24669, 24669) and data type float64

I tried configuring the system setting by assigning more memory to the page but that didn't work. I also tried to add dtype='float16' in loadtxt() function but the error message still contained 'data type float64'. Which approach can make sure the dtype is always float16 during the calculation? Other ways to reduce memory are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

> The size is 25,000 X 300

That would be 7'500'000 cells. Using `dtype = numpy.int8` that would consume 7.5 MB of memory, using `dtype = numpy.float64` eight times that, or 60 MB of memory.

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.53 GiB for an array with shape (24669, 24669)

Take a look at your error message - for some reason, Numpy is trying to allocate a 25'000 x 25'000 array. The "width" of the array (number of columns) is ~83 times bigger than expected.

> Other ways to reduce memory are also welcomed.

Read your data using `pandas.read_csv()` function instead. It's probably much better at loading/auto-detecting tabular data files than the `numpy.loadtxt()` function.

Comment: The 25000X25000 is a matrix for MDS. Can't do anything about the size. Can I keep the data type float16 in the whole computation process? It seems that it will always result in float64